# What is the locus of points in a space that are equidistant from $2$ parallel lines?

Tags: geometry

What is the locus of points in a space that are equidistant from $2$ parallel lines?

My instructor says it's a parallel line but I think that's incorrect.

Comment: Why do you think this is false? What would be your guess?

Comment: are you defining *parallel* to mean non-intersecting or some different way?

Comment: Because its in a 3 dimensional space wouldnt that mean that the answer is a parallel plane?

Comment: in 3+D, yes but in 2D he is right

Comment: The question says "in a space" and not "in a plane" the exact answer to this question is important to me because it costed me points on a test.

Comment: did he mark the correct answer?

Comment: @Bran:  Given that your own approach depends on a 3D setting, it would be an improvement to say as much in the body of the Question.   Also I'd add that "distance" means Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two lines are in $\Bbb R^n$ the points equidistant from them form an $n-1$ dimensional hyperplane.  If $n=2$ they form a line halfway between the two original lines.  If $n=3$ they form a plane that is perpendicular to the plane the lines are in going through the line between them.

Comment: How do you formally prove this in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @smth:  If you know about affine transformations you can find one that takes the two parallel lines to $x=1,y=0$ and $x=-1,y=0$.  Then observe that any point with $x=0$ is equidistant from them.  Doing it without the transformation is messier but basically the same.

Comment: @smth:   You can also construct the plane perpendicular to the lines and through a point, then work in that plane to show the set of points equidistant to the two points where the lines cut the plane is a line between them.  Project back to 3D and you have a plane.